# How to re-assign another brush tool on a stroke afterwards?

Tags: grease-pencil

I wonder if it's possible to select strokes and re-assign them another brush. I've made some drawings and I figured out afterwards that it would look better with another brush. I thought that it would be easy to reassign another brush to it as it is for materials. But I did not find a way so far...

Any idea?